# responseText is empty, but shows on console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is probably a stupid error, but I'm using JQuery ajax against PHP backend, and I would like the PHP script to post progress back to the webpage.

It looks to be working fine, but I can't get the contents of e.target.responseText.

If i do console.log(e.target), I get the XMLHttpRequest object in the console. And I can see 
responseText: "1 av 1500 linjer"

But if I do console.log(e.target.responseText) it is empty.

Have I lost my mind?

This is my function:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "modEcs/ajax/ecs.php?a=analyseExcel",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        xhrFields: 
        {
        onprogress: function(e) 
        {               
            console.log(e.target);
            console.log(e.target.responseText);  
            }
        },
        success: function(data) 
        {

         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.statusText); }
    });
```

Data in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: function(e)
onreadystatechange: null
ontimeout: null
readyState: 4
response: "1 av 1500 linjer"
responseText: "1 av 1500 linjer"
responseType: ""
responseURL: "xxx"
responseXML: null
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
withCredentials: false
XMLHttpRequest-prototype
```

Comment: Pls show us data returned from `console.log(e.target);`

Comment: I have added it

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target));` Guessing the `responseText` is not present when you do that.

Comment: It throws an error: typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.w')

Comment: Or wait, now i got something. It outputs {} to the console.

Comment: the responseText is part of XMLHttpRequest and you can't find it "e" argument. Use XMLHttpRequest in your onprogress method and check.

Comment: @TechBreak can you show an example of how I can check XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I can't test this right now, but I'm pretty sure that what you're seeing is a common confusion in viewing console data. When you log the property itself, you're logging a primitive value, and so its *current* value gets printed (empty string). When you log the entire object, you're logging a "live" view of the object, so when you go to view it in the console, the request has completed, and so you now see the completed `responseText` value.

Comment: @johnohod I have added a snippet please can you check now if that gets you close to what you want?

Comment: @squint ..so what you are saying is that, if my php function actually uses some time to complete, then I might get a value responseText? So far I have just echoed back som text.

Comment: I don't know if that property is meant to be updated progressively, but if not, then you'll not show any value when logging it directly, but it'll appear when logging the entire object because of the "live" view of that object.

Answer (score 1):

progress is only triggered during the XMLHTTPRequest, not at the end when the response was received

```
readyState 3: "Downloading; responseText holds partial data."
```

Comment: Then why can I put console.log(e.target); in the onprogress function, and get an output with data to the console?

Comment: @johnohod you get output with data because you are logging the object, which is evaluated live when you click on the console to view its properties, after the XHR is done

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "modEcs/ajax/ecs.php?a=analyseExcel",
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     xhr: function(){
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        // Handle progress
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
        //Do some progress calculations
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }, false);

   return xhr;
  },
  complete:function(){
    console.log("Request finished.");
  }
});
```

Comment: That you for that! But as far as I can see, it does exactly the same as my function. console.log(xhr.responseText); outputs a blank line to the console, but if I do console.log(xhr) an XMLHttpRequest object is outputted to the console, containing responseText with the text I want to display.

Comment: @johnohod it is different. You are not working with xhr object in your code. Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: It worked in exactly the same manner as my original function. It didn't solve anything.

Comment: @johnohod try removing if condition. It's strange as the current xmlhttprequest should exist in progress

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it will be empty in `onprogress`, because server doesn't return any data during the progress. you can only read `responseText` in success function.

The reason you can see `responseText` in console(even though you called .log() in onprogress), is because server has actually returned the data already, and called `success` function too, since you are logging whole object with e.target, the object can get updated at any time, no matter where you logged it, and console will show you its Live version, and not the version which was at the exact moment of its console logging. When object is changed, it will be updated in console too, anywhere. But `target.responseText` is a primitive, its not an object, and console won't update its value when its changed.

Hope this helps future readers.